# Mouse event cursor difference between browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use mouseover to get the cursor type, i get different results in Chrome and in Firefox when mouse is over for some reason the cursor style in Chrome is "auto" and in Firefox is "text". I need to know when the cursor is default in both browsers and when it's auto (as it's suppose to be over text input) or text. .

I wrote a simple code here to reproduce the issue, try it on both Chrome and Firefox and see the difference (here it is at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uu3bszqf/) if you want to play with the code).

Thanks in advance :)

```js
window.onmouseover=function(event) {
    var currentCursor = $(event.target).css('cursor'); 
    console.log(currentCursor);
    $('#pointer').html(currentCursor);
};
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" width="100">
<p>Move the mouse in and out the input field</p>
<p id='pointer'></p>
```

Comment: CSS can change it to whatever you want it to be. Why do you need to know the cursor type?

Comment: It's for a feature I'm building were things change according to the cursor style, I don't need to change the cursor.

Comment: So how do users without cursors use this feature?

Comment: It is directed only to desktop users with a mouse, It is a feature in a WordPress plugin I'm building.

Comment: You mentioned that it's supposed to be `auto` over the text field. Did you find that a specification somewhere?

Comment: Yes, "auto" and "text' are showing the same cursor, for example here https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/ , but in the code i wrote they don't, i searched and couldn't find a solution

Comment: @RamSegev, `auto` and `text` are not showing the same result in the link you provided. Note then the `auto` cursor will change when you hover the text inside the box, while the `text` will not.

Comment: Dekel, thanks for that, but i still have the issue with my function. why is there a difference between the browser and how can i solve it?

Comment: The difference between the browsers is due to the fact that... they are different browsers :) Each browser has it's own defaults and in this case - chrome's default cursor value for `input` is `auto`, while firefox's default is `text`. I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but if you set the values in your css (`input { cursor: text;}`) they will be the same for all browsers.

Comment: I know this are different browsers and that they acting differently, I don't need to set the values, i need to get the values and the feature will act according to the cursor change. What i need to know is how to solve it that my feature will act the same in both browsers.

Comment: Can you  give some more information regarding what you are trying to achieve? With the current info it seems like you will need to have a predefined values for each browser (since each of them treats the cursor's default behavior differently).

Comment: Im developing a wordpess plugin, this feature in the plugin will change the mouse image depending on the cursor css.Im fine with a solution of predefine values for each browser, of course i preffer a more robust solution:-D thank you in advance for trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome and Firefox probably use a different default sheet for the input controls.

If you want to be sure you can set your own stylesheet and force the cursor to be 'text' of inputs of type text.

```js
window.onmouseover=function(event) {
    var currentCursor = $(event.target).css('cursor'); 
    console.log(currentCursor);
    $('#pointer').html(currentCursor);
};
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
  cursor:text
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" width="100">
<p>Move the mouse in and out the input field</p>
<p id='pointer'></p>
```

Comment: This is brilliant, i was looking at such a dark place in js that i didn't think about css. Thanks